# How can I loop this code?

Tags: python

```
price = int(input('Enter price. '))
quan = int(input('Enter quantity. '))
total = price*quan
print('The total is ' +str(total))

price2 = int(input('Enter price. '))
quan2 = int(input('Enter quantity. '))
total2 = price2*quan2     

all_totals = total + total2
print('The sum of the totals is ' +str(all_totals))
```

Ideally, I don't want to have price2 etc.. but I need the program to loop and add together the sub totals, and then print what the whole total is. I am new to python and any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grandtotal = 0

while True:
    price = int(input('Enter price. (0 to quit) '))
    if price == 0:
        break
    quan = int(input('Enter quantity. '))
    subtotal = price*quan
    print('The subtotal is %d' % subtotal)
    grandtotal = grandtotal + subtotal

print('The sum of the totals is %d' % grandtotal)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now. I appreciate your help!

Comment: upvoted. Since you are there, suggest a better usage of `print`, maybe